# Copying list of files to a directory

Tags: bash, copying

I want to make a search for all .fits files that contain a certain text in their name and then copy them to a directory.

I can use a command called fetchKeys to list the files that contain say 'foo'

The command looks like this : `fetchKeys -t 'foo' -F | grep .fits`

This returns a list of .fits files that contain 'foo'. Great! Now I want to copy all of these to a directory `/path/to/dir`. There are too many files to do individually , I need to copy them all using one command.

I'm thinking something like:

```
fetchKeys -t 'foo' -F | grep .fits > /path/to/dir
```

or

```
cp fetchKeys -t 'foo' -F | grep .fits /path/to/dir
```

but of course neither of these works. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xargs` tool can execute a command for every line what it gets from stdin. This time, we execute a `cp` command:

```
fetchkeys -t 'foo' -F | grep .fits | xargs -P 1 -n 500 --replace='{}' cp -vfa '{}' /path/to/dir
```

`xargs` is a very useful tool, although its parametrization is not really trivial. This command reads in 500 .fits files, and calls a single cp command for every group. I didn't tested it to deep, if it doesn't go, I'm waiting your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Sorry , what do I put in the two '{}' ? I assume I will put /path/to/dir in one of them . Also there are 916 files to be copied . Thanks .

Comment: Nothing, it is what you should type in.

Comment: Hi Peter . Oops I didn't scroll to the right , I hadn't seen the /path/to/dir . Ok I ran the command and it is running now so thanks for that . It looks like it might take a while though so I will let you know when it finishes . Also if you have time , do you know if there is a way to copy to files to another server: something like :scp fetchKeys -t 'foo' | grep .fits  me@123.456.789:/path/to/dir ? thanks again .

Comment: @Derek If you are happy, why don't you accept/upvote my answer?

Comment: just accepted your answer , can't upvote you though as I need a 15 reputation to do that seemingly .

Comment: @Derek Thanks. You should use scp. And if you won't type your password after every 500 group, you should make a passwordless scp with ssh-keygen. Very probably there was ssh-keygen tutorial here on this site. I think you have this repu already. :-)

Comment: @Derek : David's and Sergey's solution looks also okay, I suggest, at least an upvote they deserve too.

Comment: Yeah my rep is over 15 now haha , ur answer has been clicked useful.  so is it just as easy as replacing cp with scp ?   fetchKeys -t SN2011bl -F | grep .fits | args -P 1 -n 500 --replace='{}' scp -vfa '{}' me@111.222:/path/to/dir   . Or do I need to make some other changes ? I tried it but it's telling me Broken Pipe .

Comment: Ok I figured it out . First I tried to transfer the files by : fetchKeys -t 'foo' -F | grep .fits | xargs -P 1 -n 500 --replace='{}' scp '{}' host@111.222:/path/to/dir     This worked but like you mentioned it asked me for the password after each file . SO I looked this ssh-keygen that you mentioned on google and managed to disable the password between the two hosts . Great , thanks for your help .

Answer (score 4):

If this is on Linux/Unix, can you use the `find` command? That seems very much like `fetchkeys`.

```
$ find . -name "*foo*.fit" -type f -print0 | while read -r -d $'\0' file
do
    basename=$(basename $file)
    cp "$file" "$fits_dir/$basename"
done
```

The `find` command will find all files that match `*foo*.fits` in their name. The `-type f` says they have to be files and not directories. The `-print0` means print out the files found, but separate them with the [NUL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) character. Normally, the `find` command will simply return a file on each line, but what if the file name contains spaces, tabs, new lines, or even other strange characters?

The `-print0` will separate out files with nulls (\0), and the `read -d $'\0' file` means to read in each file separating by these null characters. If your files don't contain whitespace or strange characters, you could do this:

```
$ find . -name "*foo*.fit" -type f | while read file
do
    basename=$(basename $file)
    cp "$file" "$fits_dir/$basename"
done
```

Basically, you read each file found with your find command into the shell variable `file`. Then, you can use that to copy that file into your `$fits_dir` or where ever you want.

Again, maybe there's a reason to use `fetchKeys`, and it is possible to replace that `find` with `fetchKeys`, but I don't know that `fetchKeys` command.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Yes it is Linux and I am ssh logging on to another server which I can use this fetchKeys command . I don't know much about it and it doesn't have a 'man'. Sorry I made a mistake , 'foo' does not exist in the filename , it is the name of an object which I assume is declared somewhere in the fits file . So fetchKeys will first find all the objects named 'foo' from within the fits file and then I use grep to single out the fits files . So I can't use find here . There are 916 files to be copied . Any ideas ?

Comment: You can use that `fetchKeys -t 'foo' -F | grep .fits` and pipe that to the `while read` command. Basically, you need to feed the files you want to copy to where ever you're doing the backup.

Comment: `read -d $'\0'` can be simplified to [`read -d ''`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174017/165042).

Answer (score 3):

Copy all files with the name containing `foo` to a certain directory:

```
find . -name "*foo*.fit" -type f -exec cp {} "/path/to/dir/" \;
```

Copy all files themselves containing `foo` to a certain directory (solution without `xargs`):

```
for f in `find . -type f  -exec grep -l foo {} \;`; do cp "$f" /path/to/dir/; done
```

The `find` command has very useful arguments `-exec`, `-print`, `-delete`. They are very robust and eliminate the need to manually process the file names. The syntax for `-exec` is: `-exec (what to do) \;`. The name of the file currently processed will be substituted instead of the placeholder `{}`.

Other commands that are very useful for such tasks are `sed` and `awk`.

Comment: Oh sorry I made a mistake , 'foo' doesn't exist in the file name , it exists in the fits file itself . it is the name of the object . So I need to use this fetchKeys command . I definitely can't use find here to single out these files . Any other ideas ? Thanks .

Comment: Sure, added a solution for this as well.